# Split NetCDF file based on latitude and longitude values

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a NetCDF file with 2.5GB with latitude values ranging from [-90, 90] and longitude values ranging from [-180, 180].

I want to split my netcdf file into smaller ones. I've tried to use CDO in the terminal:

```
     cdo -sellonlatbox,-180,-90,-90,-45 input.nc output.nc
```

But i get a System error message: Cannot allocate memory.

Can someone explain me the error that I am making or provide me with an alternative approach?

Thank you

I only have 1 time step in my data. The following image shows the characteristics of the .nc file I'm working with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ10A.png)

Comment: For operations, the minimum amount of data CDO has to take into RAM is a full horizontal layer. If you do not have multiple time steps in your data then CDO is presumably unzipping the netCDF file and essentially taking it all into memory, which is causing the error. There are ways around this, but you'd need to provide more complete info about the file you are working with, i.e. dimensions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have given you will possibly not be able to solve this using CDO. The difficulty is that you are working with data that has very high spatial resolution (300m). CDO's data model requires that a minimum of a single horizontal slice has to be read in. As a result your code sample requires the entire data file to be read into RAM. Given this is a 2 GB file that is probably zipped, you will be pushing the RAM limits on a lot of systems. In general this is not much of an issue for CDO, as this kind of resolution is rare in climate change, but obviously it is here.

The alternative would be to use NCO. The ncks command should be able to crop the data without running into RAM issues. Try the following, and then if it works modify as appropriate:

```
ncks -d lon,0.0,90.0 -d lat,0.0,90.0 infile outfile
```