# R split netcdf file into tiles

Tags: r, netcdf

I am new to netcdf in R (netcdf4 package) and I would like to split a large netcdf file with several variables into smaller tiles based on longitude and latitude.
I was able to split a single raster file into tiles using the splitRaster function (SpaDES.tools package), but I have no idea how to do this on a netcdf file. The output would ideally be several nc files, e.g clim_0012_0022.nc, clim_0013_0023.nc

My question is similar to that one:
[Split NetCDF file based on latitude and longitude values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853286/split-netcdf-file-based-on-latitude-and-longitude-values), however I would like to find a way to do it in R.

Any suggestions? Thank you!